How to handle the conflicting orientation masks between UIViewController and AppDelegate
I noticed that the Apple official documentation for UIViewController describes handling view rotation as follows:

The intersection of the app’s orientation mask and the view controller’s orientation mask is used to determine which orientations a view controller can be rotated into.

However, my actual testing shows otherwise. In the AppDelegate, I set the app to support only [.portrait]:
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        [.portrait]
    }

In the Root ViewController, I implemented the supportedInterfaceOrientations method:
    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        .landscape
    }

On my iPad running iOS 17.6, it appears that my app supports all rotation orientations and is not restricted to a specific set of orientations.
Of course, I also set Requires Full Screen to YES, and I confirmed through breakpoints that the above method was indeed called.
I would like to know if this behavior is what the official documentation intended to convey.

What, according to you, is the intersection between .landscape and .portrait?

@matt Yes, I mean, the intersection between .landscape and .portrait should be nothing, not all orientations

How could an app have no orientations?

@matt This is exactly what I'm puzzled about; it seems that the behavior is inconsistent with the documentation description.

Well, the documentation is just words. But even looking at those words, I don't see any evidence for an inconsistency. The documentation just says that "the intersection ... is used to determine which orientations a view controller can be rotated into." It doesn't say how it is used, i.e. what the rule is by which we get from the intersection to the orientations. Evidently, on iPad, the rule is that if the intersection is empty, we simply fall back on allowing all four orientations. But more generally, if you do something nonsensical (empty intersection) you must expect a suprise.

And after all, falling back on allowing all four orientations is arguably a better solution to the nonsensical thing you are doing than, say, crashing (which is what I would have expected).
